# Let the program report its local variables at certain frequency

Tags: python

Is there a way to let a running program to report(for example output to stdout) its program state (for example certain variable or locals()) at runtime at certain frequency, so that realize the tracking of the running program.

Comment: Aren't you just talking about a [logging mechanism](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)?

Comment: @Lix actually not that complex. I want to track the progress of how many percentile of data is already processed by my program. And that can be done by measuring the length of a queue at certain frequency.

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't simply use the `print` command?

Comment: @Lix  multiprocessing and the queue I want to track is not in the subprocess

Answer (score 0):

something like?

```
my_data=a_list_of_stuff
interval=some_number

for n,thing in enumerate(num_things):
    if n % interval==0: print 'I have done around %d of %d things' % (n,len(my_data))
```

this would likely be much easier to do, unless you are forced to use some scheduling mechanism that reports periodically on the length of the queue.